# How to run a timer on multiple selenium windows? (Selenium Java)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The goal of my program is it to open two firefoxdriver windows and have them both click a button at a certain time (11am for example)

How can I achieve this?

This is what I have so far, but it doesnt work and I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
public class Timetest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String geckoDriverPath = "/Users/blake/Desktop/geckodriver.exe";
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    int time = Integer.parseInt(timeStamp);
    for(int x = 0; x>2; x++) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", geckoDriverPath );
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    }
    WebElement check = driver.findElement(By.id("gb_70"));
    while(time < 110000)
    {
        timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        time = Integer.parseInt(timeStamp);
    }
    check.click();


}
```

This code ends up giving me an error on the line that says

```
WebElement check = driver.findElement(By.id("gb_70"));
```

with an error: "driver cannot be resolved"

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Your question heading is `run a timer on multiple selenium windows` where as the error you are seeing is with `findElement(By.id("gb_70").` Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Note that the error is not a runtime error but a **compile time error**. The line in which you define `driver` is not visible outside the `for` block. So, to approach your problem 1) learn about definition/declaration and visibility of variables and 2) in a Selenium context think about using multiple JVMs for concurrency effects, rather than trying to do that from within your test code in Java.